# Unassign uncategorized from post with 2 or more categories

Tags: categories

So I have a bunch of posts assigned categories like: a main one and uncategorized one (which I forgot to unselect).

The problem is that i'm using `%category%/%postname%` as permalink which will use the lower ID category in permalink, which obviously will be `uncategorized`.

How do I unassign `uncategorized` category from those posts (2000+ posts). I guess I probably need to write a query for this. Has anyone done this before?

Or should I just update the ID of `uncategorized` to a very high number?

Comment: can you tell me what is term_id & term_taxonomy of uncategorized ? is it 1?

Comment: term_id of uncategorized is 1. haven't check term_taxonomy yet

Comment: term_taxonomy_id is required to execute following query.

Comment: I'll give it a try on localhost.  Thank you Vinod.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire following query on your wordpress database to unassign uncategorized category from all posts.

```
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = term_taxonomy_id of  uncategorized category
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a plugin called Batch-Move by http://www.walchum.net/

It lets you query for posts, then select the posts you want removed from any category, and removes them from the category in a batch process.